# Add states for shipping zones instead of postcodes in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have a woocommerce website. by default in woocommerce i can limit shipping zones by zipcode. But How can I add states of my country in shipping zones so that customers can choose the state they live by a "dropdown menu" in checkout page instead of entering zip code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If states are not defined for your country in WooCommerce, you should need to defined them all with a letter code (2 or 3 uppercase characters) and the corresponding label name in an array.

Here below is an example based on France regions *(Not defined in Woocommerce)* for France country code **`'FR'`** *(so you need to set your woocommerce country code)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_states', 'add_custom_states_to_country');
add_filter('woocommerce_countries_allowed_country_states', 'add_custom_states_to_country');
function add_custom_states_to_country( $states ) {
    $states['FR'] = array(
        'AR' => __('Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes', 'woocommerce'),
        'BF' => __('Bourgogne-Franche-Comté', 'woocommerce'),
        'BR' => __('Bretagne', 'woocommerce'),
        'CV' => __('Centre-Val-de-Loire', 'woocommerce'),
        'CO' => __('Corse', 'woocommerce'),
        'IF' => __('Île-de-France', 'woocommerce'),
        'GE' => __('Grand Est', 'woocommerce'),
        'HF' => __('Hauts-de-France', 'woocommerce'),
        'NO' => __('Normandie', 'woocommerce'),
        'NA' => __('Nouvelle-Aquitaine', 'woocommerce'),
        'OC' => __('Occitanie', 'woocommerce'),
        'PL' => __('Pays de la Loire', 'woocommerce'),
        'PA' => __('Provence-Alpes-Côte d’Azur', 'woocommerce'),
    );
    return $states;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

The [**Country Iso Codes**](http://www.fedex.com/za/tracking/codes.html)

---

**In Shipping Zone Settings:**

[image]

**In Cart (shipping calculator):**

[image]

**In Checkout:**

[image]

Comment: Hi... thank you very muhc for your code. Really appreciate your help. Should I include any php end tags after pasting it in the functions.php ? Because I tried it at frist attempt, it didn't work...

Comment: I copied the same code and entered in end of functions.php file to check whether its working or not. It wasn't my friend. If i did so, it should look like your screen shots, right?

Comment: thank you very much for your solving my problem... really appreciate for your time... Great work !!

Comment: The code works great! However, I noticed that this piece of code adds a new line on the checkout page which says "State (optional)". Is there a way to change this field to be a required select tag?